# Efficient way of angularjs binding - whole object vs individual values

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have a component and a subcomponent. The subcomponent works on some data and sends the data to parent component.

So my flow goes like this:

```
component('parentComponent', {
    controller: function () {
        vm.onSubcomponentValueChange = function (obj) {
            // convert data into some other format, lets say for example
            vm.objAPIFormat = [];
            for (value in obj.somevalue1) {
                vm.objAPIFormat.push({
                    'somevalue1': value
                    'somevalue2': obj.somevalue2,
                    'somevalue3': obj.somevalue3
                });
            }
        }

        vm.onFormSubmit = function () {
            // make an API call with some complex format of obj
            // API call in service with vm.objAPIFormat
        }
    }
}

component('subComponent', {
    bindings: {
        inputObject: '<',
        onInputObjectChange: '&'
    }
    controller: function () {
        vm.$onChange = function (changes) {
            if (changes.inputObject) {
                vm.obj = changes.inputObject.currentValue;
            }
        }

        //some complex logic with vm.obj.somevalue1 = []
        //some complex logic with vm.obj.somevalue2 = ''
        //some complex logic with vm.obj.somevalue3 = ''

        vm.onSubcomponentChange= function () {
            vm.onInputObjectChange(vm.obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is, which is an efficient approach?

passing inputObject as a single object to subcomponent?
or splitting up the object into individual bindings? Like:

```
bindings: {
  somevalue1: '<',
  somevalue2: '<',
  somevalue3: '<'
  onSomeValue1Change: '&'
  onSomeValue2Change: '&'
  onSomeValue3Change: '&'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you bind one object with multiple properties, the subcomponent wont trigger the `$onChanges` event when the properties of this object changes. Only if the reference to the object changes (or the value, in case of a value type) is the `$onChanges` handler called.

So if you rely on handling the property change individually, you would have to bind them individually, or you'd have to add your own watchers to the properties in the subcomponent. The latter option would even out any saving in efficiency from having only one binding - or might even make it slightly worse.

In addition, if you only have a few instances of these components (or even just one) in the DOM at any one point, then you don't really have to bother too much with optimizing your number of component bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that one-way `<` binding only triggers the `$onChange` function when the **identity** of the object changes. If the directive needs to do things when the **contents** of the object changes, equality checking needs to be done in the `$doCheck` function:

```
component('subComponent', {
    bindings: {
        inputObject: '<',
        onInputObjectChange: '&'
    }
    controller: function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.$onChange = function (changes) {
            if (changes.inputObject) {
                vm.obj = changes.inputObject.currentValue;
            }
        };

        vm.$doCheck = function() {
            var oldValue;
            if (!angular.equals(vm.inputObject, oldValue) {
                oldValue = vm.inputObject;

                //code to update directive

            };
        };    
    }
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)
- [AngularJS angular.equals API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)